# Sencha Touch 2 Load store on demand

Tags: touch, extjs, store

Currently I have a store that I am loading in my app.js at runtime:

```
stores: ['Neighbors']
```

Its autoLoad property is set to true.

I've now added a login system that is loaded if some info isn't found in localStorage:

```
//show login if user credentials are unknown
var username = window.localStorage.getItem("email");
var user_id = window.localStorage.getItem("user_id");

if(username == '' || username == undefined || user_id == '' || user_id == undefined) {
    Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('aa.view.Login'));
} else {
    Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('aa.view.Main'));
}
```

The login view fires an ajax request to log the user in, and the user's id and some other info is returned on success:

```
onLoginButtonTap: function() {
        var values = this.getLoginForm().getValues();
        var that = this;
        // do the ajax login
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'http://localhost:8000/session',
            method: 'POST',
            params: values,
            timeout: 10000, // time out for your request

            success: function(result) {
                // let's get the email and id into local storage
                var json = Ext.decode(result.responseText);
                console.log(json);
                window.localStorage.setItem('user_id', json.user_id);
                window.localStorage.setItem('email', json.email);

                // var neighborsStore = Ext.getStore('Neighbors');
                // neighborsStore.load();


                // load up the tab holder and destroy the login view
                Ext.getCmp('loginForm').destroy();
                Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('aa.view.Main'));

            },

            failure: function(){
                Ext.Msg.alert("Login Failed");
            }
        });

    }
```

I use the user_id in my store to get a list of other users nearby. The only problem is, my user_id isn't known unless my user has logged in.

I either need to refresh the store, or I need to defer its loading until after a successful login. I'd rather do the second option and only attempt to load the store after login.

I can't seem to find any info on how to do this. I've tried

```
Ext.getStore('storename').load()
```

but it isn't refreshing the store. I've tried setting autoLoad to false but then the store never loads. How do I defer loading?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `that.getNeighborsStore().load()` in your success function. This will load the store once the user has successfully logged in.

Comment: I'll have to see if I can find this code again. This project got shelved, but I'd be interested to see if this works. Thanks!